# How do I unit test a custom ExtJS component using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, jasmine

I’m writing jasmine tests for an ExtJS 4.1.1 client app. The server side code is Java. The client app doesn’t follow a strict MVC pattern; the models are separate but the view and controller code is co-mingled. The controllers don’t even inherit from Ext.app.controller. (Don’t blame me, I didn’t write it).

I’m able to test the Ext.app.Application object but keep getting null whenever I try to create a custom ExtJS layout object inside the Jasmine spec.

It's probably a basic error in my test ExtJS app or jasmine spec but I'm very new to ExtJS and can't pin point it.

Any help is really appreciated.

File structure:

```
/myapp (java code)
    ...
    /webclient
    /assets
    /extjs-4.1.1
    /myapp (same name as top level java code)
        myapp.js
        myapp-ui.js
    /myapp-test
        runspec.html
    /lib
        /jasmine-2.3.4
    /specs
        uispecs.js
    /ui
        /layouts
            myappgrid.js
            myapppanel.js
```

Here's the code for the ExtJS app (myapp-ui.js), Jasmine specs (uispecs.js), and spec runner (runspec.html)

myapp-ui.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true,
    paths   : {
        myapp   : 'myapp'
    }
});

var Application = null;

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Application = Ext.create('Ext.app.Application', {
        name: 'myappUI',
        appFolder: 'myapp',
        autoCreateViewport: true,

        launch: function() {
            var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
            jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;
            var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter();
            jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);
            jasmineEnv.execute();
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the code for uispecs.js (Jasmine test spec)

```
describe("Basic Assumptions", function() {

   var myLayout = null;

    beforeEach( function() {
        // This always returns null
        myLayout = Ext.create('myappUI.ui.layouts.MyLayout');
    });

    // This test PASSES
    it("myappUI is defined",function() {
        expect('myappUI').toBeDefined();
    });

    // This test FAILS: myLayout is never created
    it ('myLayout shouldn’t be null', function () {
        expect ( myLayout != null).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```